# Does upgrading your speeder improve anything besides max speed?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Upgrading to the next level of speeder (level 25, 40, then 50) increases the speed while riding 10% at a time. 90%, 100%, 110%.

Are there any other benefits, besides speed, to upgrading your speeder to the next speeder level?

Comment: Note that with 4.0, all speeders are now adaptive -- meaning that the % speed increase is dependent on your Speeder Piloting rank and doesn't depend on the particular speeder.  As such, knockoff protection (as in the answer) and cosmetics are the only differences.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Yes.

Higher level speeders, in addition to traveling faster, have more 'health' -  that is to say, you'll be able to take more damage on your speeder before being automatically dismounted.

Needless to say, this is an *extremely* welcome upgrade, and is the real reason to drop the enormous sums of money on the upgraded training, rather than the minimal speed increases.

Also, it is a **proven fact** that each tier of speeder looks *11.1 percent more awesome* than the previous tier.

Comment: Found an official reference: http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?p=901740#edit901740